# Set property / attribute in a ExtJS component

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to set a Ext JS component property (visibility, value, ...) to a specific value, smilar to jQuerys `[.attr(attributeName, value)][1]`?

I'm getting the component name, the property/attribute name and the value and have to update the UI.
My first solution works with a 'dictionary' (yes, i'm a c# developer) which calls the right method for the given attribute and supports visibility, value, enabled.

```
var methodMapper = {
  "visibility" : function(comp, value) {
    if(value == "true" || value == "on" || value == "1" || value == "visible")
      comp.show();
    else
      comp.hide();
  },
  "value" : function(comp, value) {
     comp.setValue(value);
  },
  "enable" : function(comp, value) {
    if(value == "true" || value == "on" || value == "1" || value == "visible")
      comp.enable();
    else
      comp.disable();
  }
};

function receiveMessage(element, property, value) {
  var func = methodMapper[property];
  if(!func) return;
  var comp = Ext.getCmp(element); // retrieve component
  func(comp, value); // set property to value
}
```

Is there any better solution for setting the property in a component? I want to extend the supported properties to width, height, draggable, ... .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Robar

If you want to work at the attributes of an HTML element, its better that you call `getEl()` method on your ExtJS component (say panel) to get the element associated with the component and then you can get/set the attributes like how you do it in jQuery because in some cases you may not be able to map the attribute to a component property or method.

Comment: No, i don't want work with attributes of an HTML element. But as you mentioned in your last sentence, the problem is that not every attribute can be mapped to every component. I think i will go with my 'dictionary' approach and check for components type (button, textbox, ...).